# Change lookup relation parent on convert

Tags: apex, lead-conversion, after-trigger

I may have my terminology off as far as who the parent in the relationship is. However what I am trying to accomplish is take a custom object email_campagin__c attached to a lead and switch it over to the resulting opportunity when the lead is converted.

```
trigger ConvertLead on Lead (after update) {
//This trigger will associate a Custom Object record with the 
//opportunity associated to the 
//lead after it has been converted.
//The Custom Object is associated to an opportunity only if an 
//opportunity record exist on the Lead.

Email_campaign__c movedEC = new Email_campaign__c();
List<String> lead_ids = new List<String>();
//this will hold the id of the newly created opportunities.
List<id> oppids = new List<id>();
// Get only converted leads in the trigger 
 for (Lead lead : [select id, convertedopportunityid
            from Lead 
            where isConverted = true and
            id IN : Trigger.new]) {
            // store IDs of converted leads 
            lead_ids.add(lead.Id);

            oppids.add(lead.convertedopportunityid);
            }

For(Email_campaign__c movedEC : [select id from email_campaign__c where 
lead__c IN : lead_ids]){ 
    movedEC.opportunity__C = oppids;
    system.debug(movedEC.Name + '       '+oppids);
   }    
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use the existing campaign member object for this?

Comment: I am very new to Salesforce and honestly didn't know if that would be best. I am adding 50 extra custom fields and have 3 different versions w/ 3 different views depending on the type of campaign it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need separate SOQL query to retrieve `OpportunityId`. From `Trigger.new` context variable you will have that.

You have to store those Ids in the map and retrieve values from the map later for update.

Here is the approach

```
trigger ConvertLead on Lead (after update) 
{
    //This trigger will associate a Custom Object record with the 
    //opportunity associated to the 
    //lead after it has been converted.
    //The Custom Object is associated to an opportunity only if an 
    //opportunity record exist on the Lead.

    Map<Id, Id> leadOpptyMap = new Map<Id,Id>();//holds leadId as key, OpportunityId as value.

    //prepare the map from trigger context variable
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (l.IsConverted && l.convertedOpportunityId != null)
        {
            leadOpptyMap.put(l.Id, l.convertedOpportunityId);
        }
    }       

    List<Email_campaign__c> lstEmailCampaign =  [SELECT Id, lead__c, opportunity__c FROM email_campaign__c 
                                                WHERE lead__c IN : leadOpptyMap.keySet()];      
    for(Email_campaign__c movedEC : lstEmailCampaign)
    { 
        //retrieve OpportunityId from leadOpptyMap based on leadId
        movedEC.opportunity__c = leadOpptyMap.get(movedEC.lead__c);
    } 
    update lstEmailCampaign;
}
```

For more information, refer [Map Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I have a much better understanding of maps now. I will still read up on the map class! Thanks